# Windows Store App Select Statement null value

Tags: c#, windows, sqlite, windows-store-apps

My goal is to get a value out of my database and display it on the screen.

This is what I did:

```
var dbPath = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, dbName);

    conn = new SQLite.SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbPath);

    try
    {
        var Results = await conn.QueryAsync<Person>("SELECT * FROM Gebruikers where Gebruikersnaam ='" + id.Text + "'");
        TxtLabelPassword.Text = Results.Count().ToString();
        TxtLabelPassword.Text = Results.First<Person>().wachtwoord;

    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        TxtLabelPassword.Text = "Error";

    }
```

In the code you can clearly see that I am trying to get the "Gebruikersnaam" (string) out of my object.

If I count my objects in my list it will return me 1!
But then when I try to get the field out of the first object it sais it is empty.

I also made a class that was needed:

```
public class Person {

    private int ID;

    public int id
    {
        get { return ID; }
        set { ID = value; }
    }


    private string Wachtwoord;

    public string wachtwoord
    {
        get { return Wachtwoord; }
        set { Wachtwoord = value; }
    }

    private string Gebruikersnaam;

    public string gebruikersnaam
    {
        get { return Gebruikersnaam; }
        set { Gebruikersnaam = value; }
    }
    }
```

I just want to get 1 value out my object that I just got out of my database.

The error it will be give is "Null value" but I am sure that dere is 1 object in my database because my count tells me it.

Comment: Seems that you are getting the row, but are you sure that the wachtwoord column has a value in your database?

Comment: to make sure, try to do `var persons = Results.ToList()` and see what you get in `persons` variable. Is that really one `Person` object there?

Comment: @har07 I got "System.collections.generic.list'1[Test_SQlite.itemspage1+person]" when I printed out persons.  Not sure what this means o.0 (test_sqlite is my database & itemspage1 is my page i am working in)

Comment: I don't mean to print it like `persons.ToString()`, that won't add much information. I meant, put breakpoint after that line and see content of `persons` (hover on it, or use Visual Studio's watch window)

Comment: @har07 ow, it sais everywhere null but how is that possibel because in my database the data i set right, http://prntscr.com/2sopit. it also sais dere is 1 object [0]

Comment: could you upload a screenshot of what you see in `persons` variable? I don't get it clearly from comment above

Comment: @har07 http://prntscr.com/2sovsj

Comment: I don't know about SQLite you are using, but that behavior is like `.FirstOrDefault()` method behavior, that returns one default object (all properties of that object set to default value, 0, null, or empty string) if no data matched the query.

Comment: It can see how many rows I have but it cannot return the data -.-

Comment: Do you need to escape quotes?